# Emacs DNS lookup

Tags: emacs, dns

I noticed, when my network is down, Emacs is starting a lot slower. stracing it, it shows how emacs is trying to resolve hostname :S

Anyone knows how to disable this? Why emacs is needs hostname?

Also, I'm keeping .emacs minimal and double checked if some of modules using dns or any network queries.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A very similar issue was recently discussed [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/emacs-freezes-doing-dns-lookup-877625/).